# How do I write invoices in LaTeX?

Tags: letters

I'm relatively new to TeX, which means I did nothing more than homework and some math things with it.

Now I'd like to write invoices with LaTeX (for reusability etc.)

*I am not searching for a template.*

What I'm looking for is actually more a starting point and maybe some resources that already helped other people to get started with writing invoices or similar kinds of documents.

Where should I start in order to learn to write more complex documents with LaTeX?
What helped you?

Answer (score 6):

There's a list of resources in CTAN that could be useful: [Writing invoices](http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#factur)

Answer (score 1):

Invoices are -- usually -- letters. You need to know the requirements for invoices of your country. E.g. in Germany you need to number consecutively all your invoices of a year.

In case your invoices consist of many single items plus price and you need something like longtable to print all positions, you are in trouble. There is, as far as  I know, no way to have subtotals at the bottom of the page.

You could start learning LaTeX *and* Lua, because there will be an engine named "LuaTeX" (there are beta-versions already available), which can be used to calculate inside your *.tex-file. I'd be very surprised if there were no packages or at least code examples how to calculate and print invoices using LuaTeX until end of the year.

Become a member of your local TUG. In Germany that would be Dante e.V.

Regards,
Alexander

Comment: By "subtotals at the bottom of the page" you refer to invoices that are longer than one page because of the large amount of positions, is that correct? I sometimes have a few positions, however in most cases only one.

Comment: @MartinKlepsch Sorry, didn't notice your question.  However, YES, I reffered to invoices consisting many items.